# C# Framework 4.0 Rewrite URL (with period in url)

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, url-rewriting

I'm breaking my head on this one, i've been trying to rewrite my urls in many way suggested here and on other sites, including rewrite via "Intelligencia"'s rewriter and .net routing. Same result, ain't working.

Need to rewrite:

```
http://example.com/radio.aspx?station=100.5FM&name=best-radio
```

To:

```
http://example.com/station/100.5fm/name/best-radio
```

All works well on localhost when using IIS 8 express. Problem happens on server using IIS 6. Also tried adding:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

My hosting company said their solution is to upgrade the server to use IIS 7 (which from reading many answers seems to be the solution) but it doubles my monthly hosting price.

Comment: What host are you using? IIS 6 is fairly deprecated.

Comment: local company, but upgrading my server only because of this issue isn't realistic (price-wise)

Comment: I'm not sure what that company is charging, but there are hosting plans out there for fairly cheap that will give you a more up-to-date server than IIS 6.  I mean, if that's indeed the answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that working with "Intelligencia" in a vb.net framework 2 (also iis 6) web application works like a charm.. So i'm guessing that somewhere around the world there's a costless solution for c#.net framework 4 too.